# Mercurial: Tag the current revision with a name that is defined in a text file

Tags: windows, mercurial, cmd

Normally in Mercurial if I want to tag the current revision i do this:

`hg tag version12`

This will tag my current revision to "version12"

Now suppose that the text "version12" is located in a file called `buildNumbers.txt` How can I issue a DOS command to tag it with the text contained within the `buildNumbers.txt` file?

What I already tried was piping the text file in.

`hg tag < buildNumbers.txt`

But that results in HG just giving me the help screen again.  That tells me it doesen't understand this command.

So does anyone know how to extract the version number from the text file and provide it as a parameter ?

Comment: `<` is use to redirect the standard input, not to provide arguments on the command line.

Comment: Right, but I was hoping that hg tag would be able to understand the input as the tag label.  But i guess it doesen't support that.  So that's why I'm asking here if anyone knows how to extract this string from the text file and present that as a parameter to "hg tag"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given buildNumbers.txt containing just one line with one tag (no whitepsace):

`for /f %v in (buildNumbers.txt) do hg tag %v`

If the structure of buildNumbers.txt is more compilcated (you didn't specify it), see the "options" to the for command.

Comment: No I think this will work!  greatly appreciated.  Sorry about not accepting others,  but I didn't want to rely on the existence of powershell.

Comment: Agreed.  Sometimes a large sledghammer with a .NET VM is not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [`PowerShell`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/powershell) script if your `buildNumbers.txt` is a oneliner!

**UrdaNumber.txt Contents:**

```
1.0
```

**UrdaHgTag.ps1:**

```
$ver = cat .\UrdaNumber.Txt
hg tag $($ver)
```

This will tag the current revision to `1.0` if executed inside the repository.

Answer (score 1):

Would this be what you need?

```
D:\code>md htagtest

D:\code>echo bla>tagfile

D:\code>hg init

D:\code>touch a b c

D:\code>hg add a b c

D:\code>hg commit -m first

D:\code>cat tagfile | xargs hg tag

D:\code>hg log
changeset:   1:2dce938a816a
tag:         tip
user:        Tempos
date:        Sat Sep 17 00:34:36 2011 +0300
summary:     Added tag bla for changeset 349e58fd49a1

changeset:   0:349e58fd49a1
tag:         bla
user:        Tempos
date:        Sat Sep 17 00:34:27 2011 +0300
summary:     first


D:\code>
```

Comment: except cat and xargs aren't standard dos commands, are you using http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/ ?

Comment: @jk, I also have git on my system. I think they come with it. Instead of cat, `type` can be used. I don't think there's a built-in `xargs` alternative.

Answer (score 1):

Another powershell version, that does it in one line with pipes:

```
cat buildnumber.txt | %{hg tag $_}
```

note this uses a loop, so if you have more than one line in your file you will have to use `Select-Object` as well, unless you *want* multiple tags

```
cat buildnumber.txt | Select-Object -first 1 | %{hg tag $_}
```